# Test name with template literal is evaluated before variables are initialized

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I have a test with this structure:

```
for (let inputFile of inputFiles) {
    describe(`Testing ${inputFile}`, function () {
        let var1, var2, var3; //variables initialized in before hook

        before(async function () {
            //initializing var1, var2 and var3
        });


        it(`Result ${var1} matches something`, function (done) {
            let someVariable = 4;
            assert.equal(someVariable, var1)
            done();
        });
    });
}
```

The test gives the right success or failure status based on the variables initialized in the before hook, but the name of the test in the code above appears as *"someVariable is undefined"*, even though in the scope of the callback function provided to it() var1 is already initialized. I guess mocha evaluates all tests name before any hook gets called.

Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: `var1` is evaulted immediately upon invokation. If you want it to be named based on what happens in `setTimeout`, you need to place it after you do your operations in `setTimeout`

Comment: Where is someVariable defined?

Comment: @epascarello I edited the code defining someVariable, even though it doesn't change anything about what I'm asking.